# Bootstrap carousel not displaying all images

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

The buttons aren't working on my bootstrap carousel and it doesn't go to the other images. I haven't changed anything carousel related in the Bootstrap CSS or JavaScript.

Here is my code so far:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>    
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active"><img src="images/oldman1.jpg" alt="First slide" style="height: 50%; width: 100%; display: block;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Generations Apart</h1>
            <p>An Empathic Photo Essay</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="Childhood.html">Begin</a>   </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"><img src="images/oldman2.jpg" alt="Third slide" style="height: 50%; width: 100%; display: block;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Generations Apart</h1>
            <p>An Empathic Photo Essay</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="Childhood.html">Begin</a></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"><img src="images/oldman.jpg" alt="Third slide" style="height: 50%; width: 100%; display: block;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Generations Apart</h1>
            <p>An Empathic Photo Essay</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="Childhood.html">Begin</a></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> 
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> 
</a>
</div>
```

Links to JS/CSS:

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
         <link href="css/custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
         <link href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
         <title>Generations Apart</title>
    </head>
```

Comment: Can you post your javascript? Or better a Jsfiddle?

Comment: I've just used the standard bootstrap js as the carousel is a feature of bootstrap. I could post it but there's an awful lot of it!

Comment: Please post up your js/css links etc so we can see if that all looks okay.

Comment: added them at the bottom

Comment: Are you using a live site? If so. Can we see it?

Comment: Can you post your custom.css? I think the issue is with that as your markup works as is in a vanilla bootstrap site.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bootply.com/127038

Sorry as you can see here your code works well and it runs the carousel without any problem.

Are you sure that the JS and CSS file that you are linking are exactly where u are linking to?